# Quadruped Robot Visualization and TF Problems In towr and xpp

Tags: ros-melodic, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello.
I try to visualize my own special robot with towr. I have already added the kinematic and dynamic models of my robot. But when i try to visualize in Rviz, the joints of the robot occur at very meaningless angles. [It will be more descriptive in the video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DKZuQ7vOjOo). When I look at the TF tree, I see the TF data of two robots at the same time. My Robot (It appears in the video as Vira) and HyQ robot.

I'm working on the guide on towr and xpp but I don't know clearly where to approach the problem.
Thank you for your help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/350545/quadruped-robot-visualization-and-tf-problems-in-towr-and-xpp/) by [Murat](https://answers.ros.org/users/44145/murat/) on ROS Answers with karma: 55 on 2020-04-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My first guess would be that the inverse kinematics function might have some bugs. This needs to be supplied by the user to xpp. You can reuse the one from the xpp HyQ example, but only if your kinematic tree is the similar and you adjust the frames and link parameters. So I would check that function, the conversion from cartesian endeffector positions to joint angles.

Hope this helps, best of luck :)

---

Originally posted by [Alexander Winkler](https://answers.ros.org/users/33039/alexander-winkler/) with karma: 26 on 2020-04-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Murat](https://answers.ros.org/users/44145/murat/) on 2020-04-26**:
I applied  simple motion planning to my own robot by working on monoped_pub in the xpp guide. As a result, the robot's foots (kinematic structure) didn't follow endeffectors. As you said, there must be a bug with ik then converting ee positions in to joint angles should be main focus point. It has a slightly different kinematic structure. I will concentrate on inverse kinematics, taking into account what you say.
Thank you so much!